# Como atualizar Repeater ASP.NET em tempo real?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um Repeater em uma div lateral que recebe a quantidade de produtos do carrinho e precisa ser atualizada a cada clique.

Já tentei `rpt.Databind()` no evento Click mas o repeater só atualiza com um refresh do browser..
Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Tem como tu nos fornecer o código do evento Click?

Comment: Consegui resolver chamando updatePanel.Update();

Comment: Ótimo, boa sorte :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você poderá utilizar um update panel e colocar uma trigger ou evento para atualizar a página a cada requisição que você quiser.

Tente algo assim:

```
 GridView1.DataBind();
 UpdatePanel1.Update();
```

Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 1):

Você terá de fazer isso usando `javascript` no lado do cliente, ao invés de usar um repeater.

Eu recomendo que você use jQuery, para poder fazer isso, além de um plugin de templates muito bom: https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates

Você provavelmente terá de pegar o elemento que deve ser atualizado, por exemplo, uma `div` que contém a lista de elementos que quer atualizar, e dar um append nele, para inserir cada novo item:

```
$("#idElementoContainerLista").append(htmlElemento);
```

Sendo que a variável `htmlElemento` pode ser construída usando uma string puramente:

```
"<div>... mais html do elemento aqui...</div>"
```

Ou então usando o plugin de template... caso a opção da string comece a ficar complicado demais.